# how to add modules/apps to a virtualenv project?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install nathan burrows basic apps on my computer https://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps

> Simple apps for Django projects.
>
> To install any of the apps listed simply create a folder on your
>   PYTHONPATH named 'basic' and place the apps you wish to use in that
>   folder. Then added basic. to your project's settings.py
>   file. (replace  with the apps you wish to use, naturally).

I have set up a virtualenv project and copy/pasted the "blog" app folder of burrows to my project folder. 
Directory structure: 
MainvirtualenvFolder----------->(Basic, Mysite, manage.py)
Basic folder has "blog" app folder.
Mysite folder has usual django files like settings, etc.

I have edited settings.py "Insalled Apps" to include "basic.blog".

However, when running manage.py (under virtualenv ofcourse), I get the error:

> Error: No module named basic.blog

What am i doing wrong?

EDIT -

```
> ^C(mike)prince@kingdom:~/projects/mike/basicsite$ python manage.py
> syncdb Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 10,
> in <module>
>     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/home/prince/projects/mike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
> line 443, in execute_from_command_line
>     utility.execute()   File "/home/prince/projects/mike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
> line 382, in execute
>     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/home/prince/projects/mike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 196, in run_from_argv
>     self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)   File "/home/prince/projects/mike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 231, in execute
>     self.validate()   File "/home/prince/projects/mike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 266, in validate
>     num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)   File "/home/prince/projects/mike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py",
> line 30, in get_validation_errors
>     for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():   File "/home/prince/projects/mike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py",
> line 158, in get_app_errors
>     self._populate()   File "/home/prince/projects/mike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py",
> line 67, in _populate
>     self.load_app(app_name)   File "/home/prince/projects/mike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py",
> line 88, in load_app
>     models = import_module('.models', app_name)   File "/home/prince/projects/mike/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py",
> line 35, in import_module
>     __import__(name)   File "/home/prince/projects/mike/basicsite/basic/blog/models.py", line 10,
> in <module>
>     import tagging ImportError: No module named tagging
```

Comment: if i try blog only, it breaks the code inside blog. i did do it and i get several errors.

Comment: for example - from basic.blog.managers import PublicManager

Comment: oh and even tried mike.basic.blog ------ mike being the directory 1 level up. still the same error. 

    Error: No module named mike.basic.blog

Comment: Did you put __init__.py inside basic folder?

Comment: i didnt. Now i did and i get a long list of errors. see above post. I know u might not help me with there errors but take a look if you recognise them. disclaimer - new to django.

Comment: it's third party app. search for django tagging app then pip install... dont forget to put it in settings installed app after installing

Comment: i figured that out. lol dependencies. my first app. soz. thx anyways

Comment: sure you can! i will accept obviously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `__init__.py` inside basic folder.

If there is missing module again inside that app:

1. Search for that module
2. `pip install`
3. put that module in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`

Comment: appreciate it. taught me three things.

Comment: That's ok we really experienced that from the start